# Secure IFRAME nested on non-secure page

Tags: iframe, ssl, cross-domain

I have a client that, due to specific reasons, needs to place an `IFRAME` pointing to an HTTPS page on an HTTP page. The HTTP page is hosted on a different domain and server than the HTTPS page, but are both owned by the same client.

Putting aside the reasons why this **should** not be done, I am finding it difficult to implement in practice.

As one can see on this page: http://www.clevelandutilities.com/obppay.htm there is a HTTPS `IFRAME` on an HTTP page without any warnings from the browser (Firefox OR IE). However, if I try the same method, both Firefox and IE complain about the certificate.

Any ideas on why that is? I've examined the source at that sample site and can see nothing special being done, yet if I try the same thing I get squawking. Further, if I put the domain that they are using (https://www.paybill.com/cu/), it doesn't complain - if I put our domain it, it complains. **Are all SSL certificates created equal?**

To boil it down, this works without warnings:

```
<iframe src="https://www.paybill.com/cu/" width="100%" height="600" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

this does not:

```
<iframe src="https://www.myclientdomain.com/somepage.php" width="100%" height="600" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

Further, we use an `IFRAME`-style Facebook app to pipe in to this same HTTPS page, and THAT works with no complaints about the SSL certificate. Huh?!

Comment: When you visit the iframe source (`https://www.example.com/somepage.php`) do you get a certificate error? It may be that the certificate CA isn't properly trusted. It might also help if you can give the error message - is it untrusted CA, time expired, wrong domain etc?

Comment: We figured it out, posted the reason below if you're curious. /facepalm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After digging a bit, we uncovered that the certificate is specific to **www**.myclientdomain.com, and the developer in charge had used `...src="https://myclientdomain.com"...` in the `IFRAME`. This was causing the following "Connection is untrusted" error screen:

[image: Untrusted error screenshot]

The common practice for the host domain is to never use 'www' in the URL (enforced with .htaccess), whereas the standard for the source domain (the one with the certificate) is to always use it (enforced with .htaccess). That's what lead the other developer to leave it off - that's what he is used to for his site.

If one clicked "I understand the risks" even once for the source domain and added the certificate exception, any visit thereafter would have made it to the htaccess and be redirected to www-, which is why on my (and the other developer's) computer the page would load fine and check out normal in Firebug while our boss got the warning. We had both (apparently) added the exception for one reason or another in the past.

When we put it together, it was a real facepalm moment. Thanks to anyone who had given this question thought, sorry to have not checked the details carefully enough. :)